# Is Graph 2-Coloring NP-Complete?

Tags: graphs, np-complete, np, colorings

I know there is a polynomial time algorithm for 2-coloring. But should the answer be "No" or should it be "Maybe"?
Since 2-coloring is in NP and we dont know if there is a reduction of any NP-complete to 2-color.

Comment: If P≠NP, then the answer is "no". If P=NP, then the answer is "almost certainly not". 2-colouring is not only in P, there is a linear-time algorithm on a random access machine. If a problem solvable in linear time turned out to be NP-hard, that would be extremely surprising indeed, but I don't know that this has ever been disproven formally.

Comment: All polynomial problems are in NP. This doesn't make them NP-complete or anything like that. NP-complete problems refer to the "hardest" in the class NP.

Comment: Yes, but for the purpose of answering the question, its still a Maybe right? @Pseudonym

Comment: @Pseudonym if P=NP they all collapse, so the answer is yes.

Comment: @Eugene I think you'd have to show that graph colouring is P-hard.

Comment: @Pseudonym post as answer?

Comment: @Pseudonym I disagree. If P=NP then every problem in P is NP-complete. You mix the reductions. For many-one reduction it's easy to show it is NP-complete you just solve it directly. Your notion about P-complete doesn't related to many-one poly time reductions at all.

Comment: @Pseudonym A linear-time problem being **NP**-complete would be no more surprising than a cubic-time problem being **NP**-complete. You'd just need to do a bit more work in the reduction.

Comment: Fair point @DavidRicherby. You can probably make any problem linear if you're allowed to use a superlinear reduction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since graph 2-coloring is in P and it is not the trivial language ($\emptyset$ or $\Sigma^*$), it is NP-complete if and only if P=NP.